# PHP: Llamada a la base de datos dentro de otra llamada a la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando hacer una llamada "pequeña" a mi base de datos dentro de otra llamada "más grande" y querría saber si es posible o si he de abordar el problema desde otra perspectiva.

Se trata de una web de música con recopilatorios años a año durante cinco décadas distintas: la llamada "grande" obtiene toda la información necesaria para mostrar vídeos, portadas de discos, información sobre las canciones, etc; la "pequeña" obtiene la nota que el usuario ha dado a las canciones. Cada canción viene acompañada de un sistema de votación de 1 a 5 (que es lo que estoy empezando a implementar ahora, echándole un ojo a AJaX), y querría que cuando el usuario se loguea, las canciones que ha votado no aparezcan con cero votos, sino con la nota dada en otras visitas a la web.

Os muestro el código, incluido en un archivo llamado `videos.php` que es llamado desde otros archivos mediante `include`, los cuales contienen la sentencia SQL, cada uno con sus peculiaridades: `decadas.php`, que sólo muestra las tres canciones más votadas de la década, y `recopilatorios.php`, que muestra las quince canciones que tiene cada recopilatorio.

El código de `videos.php`:

```
<?php   

    $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados))
    {
        $enlace_youtube = $fila['enlace_youtube'];
        $titulo_cancion = utf8_encode($fila['titulo_cancion']);
        $nombre_autor = utf8_encode($fila['nombre_autor']);
        $enlace_rym = $fila['enlace_rym'];
        $nombre_ciudad = utf8_encode($fila['nombre_ciudad']);
        $nombre_pais = utf8_encode($fila['nombre_pais']);
        $votos_facebook = $fila['votos_facebook'];
        $tipo = $fila['tipo'];
        $titulo_disco = utf8_encode($fila['titulo_disco']);
        $ano = $fila['ano'];
        $id_cancion = $fila['id_cancion'];

        $inicio = strpos($enlace_youtube, "watch?v=");
        $enlace_youtube = substr_replace($enlace_youtube, "embed/", $inicio, 8);

        if(strpos($nombre_autor, ", The")) $nombre_autor = "The ".substr($nombre_autor, 0, strpos($nombre_autor, ", The"));

        $decada = substr($ano, 0, 3)."0s";

        if(strpos($titulo_disco, "/")) $nombre_foto = substr($titulo_disco, 0, strpos($titulo_disco, "/"));
        elseif(strpos($titulo_disco, ":")) $nombre_foto = substr($titulo_disco, 0, strpos($titulo_disco, ":"));
        else $nombre_foto = $titulo_disco;

        if($condicion == true) $ano_disco = '('.$ano.')';
        else $ano_disco = null;

        $contador++;

        echo '<div class="row contenedor-youtube pt-4"><iframe class="youtube" width="575" height="323.5" src='.$enlace_youtube.' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>'; #Vídeo

        ?>

        <div class="row pt-2"> <!-- Portada, información y sistema de votación -->

            <div class="contenedor-portada mr-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-imagen"> <!-- Portada -->
                <?php echo '<img class="portada" src="imagenes/'.$decada.'/'.$ano.'/'.$nombre_foto.'.jpg" width="150" height="150">'; ?>
            </div>

            <div id="modal-imagen" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <img id="modal-imagen-in" style="width: 100%">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col"> <!-- Información y sistema de votación -->

                <div class="row"> <!-- Información (con clasificación) -->

                    <div class="mr-3"> <?php echo '<span class="numero" data-contador="'.$contador.'">'.$contador.'</span>'; ?> </div> <!-- Clasificación -->

                    <div class="col informacion"> <!-- Información -->
                        <div class="row"><?php echo '<div class="puntos"><span class="titulos cancion">'.$titulo_cancion.'</span> de&nbsp<span><a class="autor-recopilatorio" href="'.$enlace_rym.'" target="_blank">'.$nombre_autor.'</a></span></div>'; ?></div>
                        <div class="row"><?php echo '<div class="puntos">('.$nombre_ciudad.', '.$nombre_pais.')</div>'; ?></div>
                        <div class="row"><?php echo '<div class="puntos">Incluida en su '.$tipo.'&nbsp<span class="titulos">'.$titulo_disco.'</span>&nbsp'.$ano_disco.'</div>'; ?></div>
                        <div class="row "><?php echo '<span class="votos">'.$votos_facebook.'&nbsp</span>'; if($votos_facebook == 1) echo 'voto'; else echo 'votos'; ?></div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="row"> <!-- Sistema de votación -->

                    <span class="estrellas mt-3 ml-2">

                        <?php 

                            if($_SESSION['conectado'])
                            {
                                /*include("conexion.php");

                                $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

                                $sql = "SELECT nota FROM votan WHERE id_usuario = $id_usuario AND id_cancion = $id_cancion";

                                $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

                                while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)) $nota = $fila['nota']; 

                                mysqli_close($conexion);*/

                                for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$id_cancion.'" value="'.$i.'"><i></i>';
                            }   

                        ?>

                    </span>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <?php
    }

?>
```

La clave está aquí:

```
<?php 

    if($_SESSION['conectado'])
    {
        /*include("conexion.php");

        $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

        $sql = "SELECT nota FROM votan WHERE id_usuario = $id_usuario AND id_cancion = $id_cancion";

        $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

        while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)) $nota = $fila['nota']; 

        mysqli_close($conexion);*/

        for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) echo '<input type="radio" name="'.$id_cancion.'" value="'.$i.'"><i></i>';
    }   

?>
```

Si descomento la llamada, el bucle se detiene tras mostrar el primer vídeo, y la web queda así:

Ejemplo de `decadas.php`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Habrían de aparecer otros dos vídeos, correspondientes a la segunda y a la tercera canción más votadas.

Ejemplo de `recopilatorios.php`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Habrían de aparecer otros 14 vídeos y además un `iframe` de Spotify en la `col` de la derecha. En este caso sí aparecen errores de PHP pero hacen referencia a ese `iframe` precisamente, que tiene su propia llamada a la base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT enlace_spotify FROM listas WHERE ano = $recopilatorio";
    $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultados))
    {
        $enlace_spotify = $fila['enlace_spotify'];

        echo '<iframe style="color: red;" src="'.$enlace_spotify.'" width="450" height="840" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>';
    } 

    mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Bien, es obvio que esto no funciona, y me pregunto si se podría incluir la llamada "pequeña" a modo de excepción o similar, para que si la canción no ha sido votada le adjudique directamente un cero, por ejemplo, o directamente esta estructura no tiene sentido y he de probar otra cosa.

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que no es posible que puedas reutilizar una conexión mientras estás recurriendo un resultado que la esté utilizando. Y tiene sentido, considerando que mysqli_fetch_assoc te devuelve una siguiente fila o false...

Como yo lo veo, para `video.php`, habría dos soluciones posibles una por SQL y la otra por PHP.

Por PHP primero cargaría las filas de del primer SELECT a una variable y luego recorreria esa variable:

```
<?php
    $resultados = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
    $filas = [];
    while ($filas[] = msqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)); // aquí va cargando las filas, observa el [] en $filas[]
    mysqli_close($conexion); // a partir de este punto ya tengo cargado $filas y $conexion está libre

    // Ahora en lugar de recorrer $resultados, recorres $filas
    //while ($fila = msqli_fetch_assoc($resultados)) {
    for($filas as $filas) {
        $enlace_youtube = $fila['enlace_youtube'];
        $titulo_cancion = utf8_encode($fila['titulo_cancion']);
        $nombre_autor = utf8_encode($fila['nombre_autor']);
        ... // El resto de tu código, dónde ahora sí podrás usar la conexión para obtener el puntaje que dio el usuario
   }
```

Ahora la solución por SQL, supongo que la tabla `votan` relaciona una canción con el voto de un usuario, entonces sólo cabe hacer un left join entre `cancion` y `votan` (Estoy suponiendo que `nota` es el puntaje dado a la canción) para que en el resultado ya exista un campo nota:

```
SELECT c.enlace_youtube, c.titulo_cancion, c.otras_columnas,..., COALESCE(v.nota, 0) as nota -- Con COALESCE si el usuario no voto una canción establezco que sea nota sea 0
FROM cancion as c 
    LEFT JOIN votan as v
        on c.id_cancion = v.id_cancion
WHERE v.id_usuario = $un_parametro_con_el_id_usuario
```

Este SQL es el que recibirías en tu variable $sql y de ahí sólamente recorres el resultado sin necesidad de hacer tu *llamada pequeña* porque ya está resuelta la nota de la canción.

Comment: La verdad es que como sólo uso NATURAL JOIN en mis consultas se me había pasado por alto la posibilidad de hacer un LEFT JOIN, ¡gracias!

Comment: El problema que encuentro es que al incluir la cláusula AND id_usuario = $id_usuario sólo devuelve las canciones que ese usuario ha votado, no todas.

Comment: Al final lo he resuelto tirando de PHP, muchas gracias.